# Azure Active Directory notification when group membership change detected

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-monitoring

I was asked to prepare solution for sending user notification when he has been added or removed from specific Azure AD group. I am thinking of Azure Monitor service, and an alert creation, but I am not sure its appropriate service. I am not expecting whole solution, just only the direction, what azure service can I user in order to accomplish my task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best bet is to use Microsoft Graph [change notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) to monitor for group membership changes, and detect which ones you are interested in.

Alternatively, you could use Azure Monitor and alert on the appropriate [Azure AD audit event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-activity-logs-azure-monitor).